# How does a device report the difference between BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB and BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC to BatteryManager?

Tags: android, batterymanager

I understand there are two different flags and they represent whether the device is plugged into AC or USB charging. How does the device know that, and what does it report to the operating system?

I would have thought the OS could not distinguish between the phone plugged into the USB port of a laptop and charging at 500 mA, vs. the phone plugged into a wall charger and charging at 500 mA.

- Perhaps the difference is the current the device is charging at? (If so, what is the minimum current for 'AC'? Is the device free to define the cutoff?)
- Or is the difference that the device can also communicate data over its cable? That seems like a strange way to distinguish the two.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a common `AC` charger-adapter has no `USB` host-controller available (unidirectional), contrary to a `USB` port on a computer (bidrectional). my wall outlet with two charge-only `USB` ports still behaves different than my `QC4` charger-adapter, with is being detected as "turbo power" ...which is the third mode, which it is able to detect - and where at least a charging controller should be present, in order to negotiate the volts and ampere used for charging. meanwhile there even is [QC4+](https://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/mobile-computing/features/quick-charge) available. there also is `BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS` ...eg. [PowerMat](https://www.powermat.com), also only for compatible devices.

Comment: Aha, thanks. So the device and OS can't really tell if what's on the other side of the connection is a literal wall charger vs. a laptop, 

e.g. 

if a phone connected to a laptop's charge-only ports (with no data lines), Android would report as "AC", 

and a phone connected to a battery power bank with no data connection would also show as "AC"

Comment: @faradaic think that even charging via `USB` can be bidirectional... because it drains the juice from my smartphone when I keep it connected - and the PC has an UPS connected (which charges from the smartphone battery then, despite it shouldn't). also have microUSB cables, which have different charging directions, depending on the pin layout. `USB uses a master/slave star architecture. Master supplies power.`